# Match regex expression Regex sketchengine (doesn't match substring)

Tags: regex

I am learning about regular expressions and I'm trying to solve this question: https://regex.sketchengine.co.uk/cgi/ex1.cgi

So far, I've come up with:

```
^[psr][^ta|?!ea].*$
```

But instead of checking if it doesn't match 'ea' as a substring, it tries to not match 'e' and 'a' as a second character. What is my error in this?

Comment: May be: `^(?:[sr]|p[^tae]).*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is wrong, see its description:

| NODE | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string |
| `[psr]` | any character of: 'p', 's', 'r' |
| `[^ta|?!ea]` | any character except: 't', 'a', ' |
| `.*` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `$` | before an optional \n, and the end of the string |

Use

```js
.*p[ioa ]t.*
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/xXePf9/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  p                        'p'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [ioa ]                   any character of: 'i', 'o', 'a', ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  t                        't'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern you do not allow matching `pe` `se` and `re` ruling out `respite`, but you only don't want to allow `pe`.

You could use a negative lookahead to rule out a `p` directly followed by one of your characters in the character class.

```
^(?!p[tea])[psr].*
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?!p[tea])` Negative lookahead, assert not `pt` or `pe` or `pa` directly to the right
- `[psr].*` Match either `p` `s` `r` followed by 0+ times any character

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hSjhxP/1)

**Note** that there are no `|` `?` or `!` in the example data.